# Testing CNN model using sound generated from pyroomacoustics room simulation

Tags: python, sound, array-signal-processing, localization

I have generated a large set of audio using Pyroomacoustics for room simulation, employing a circular microphone array and a single sound source.

I have successfully trained and tested a CRNN (Convolutional Recurrent Neural Network) model with this audio dataset to predict events and DOA estimation.

However, when using the trained model to predict the estimated DOA of sound from a Respeaker v4 mic-array, the prediction was not correct for all the different sound type. Despite both setups having a similar mic-arrangement in the simulated scenarios.
Example of sample testing:
Actual DOA from respeaker - 90degree
Estimated DOA from respeaker - 170degree

Why i'm I getting a wrong estimated angle?

I've observed differences in the spectrograms between the WAV generated from the Pyroomacoustics room simulation and the Respeaker even after making sure both scenerio are the same. Is it possible to adjust the room simulation parameters to generate audio with a spectrogram more closely resembling that of the Respeaker?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Signal Processing SE. The way you present your problem doesn’t provide much information. You describe unsatisfactory results but you don’t provide either the results or the results you expected to get in some way. You ask whether you can estimate DoAs with some array which you do **not** describe and you suggest there are differences in spectrograms between cases you do not adequately describe and you don’t describe what these differences are either. There’s not much one in information about you problem that someone could use to help you here. Please add some more info.